# (Tempo) Dotted minim/half note = c. 60 meaning

Tags: tempo

What does a dotted minim/half note =c.60 mean? What does the c mean? And how much BPM is this?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you play the piece at 60 BPM per dotted minim, which is the same as 180 BPM per crotchet. The C, as far as I know is an abbreviation for circa which means around. So around 60 BPM.

Comment: And how would you count it? Would you just count it by crotchet? So it becomes 1+2+3+ 1+2+3+. But if you count this way, wouldn't it be really fast?

Comment: Yes, you would count it by crotchet. (1, 2, 3). It is fast but not unmanageable (in my humble opinion)

Answer (score 2):

The writer has designated the dotted minim as the 'beat', and said that there will be about 60 of them in a minute. This makes each bar last just one second. It's not easy to time bars in that way, but setting a metronome at 60bpm will help you play each first note of each bar on a click.

If you wanted a click on each crotchet, then set the metronome for a pretty quick 180bpm, and play the left hand part along to that. A student of mine would say 'el-e-phant' for each bar. and keep time to that.

Comment: Most "real" metronomes have settings for 176 and 184 with nothing in between.  Fortunately, the _c_ gives one some leeway.  Or else you have a digital metronome on your phone ;-)